# Explorer favorites (links) are the same as favorites in IE

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, favorites

Using Windows XP Pro.
Helpdesk from my work screwed up installing my new laptop and now favorites in explorer are the same as in internet explorer. They said something about MUI and changing the language, but don't know how to fix it.

Anybody know how? I looked for using regedit.exe for this, but can't figure out where the links are located. I think they deleted it?

Comment: "I would like to have two different favorites folders, one for .url and IE and one for .lnk and windows explorer." (from your deleted answer which you should have posted as a comment or an update to your question) - You cannot modify how IE and Win Explorer's Favorites are integrated in XP. Create separate sub-folders under Favorites and group your IE and Win Explorer favorites separately.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the Favorites folder in XP is generally:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Favorites
```

If in doubt check the **Favorites** REG_SZ value in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellFolders
```

If you add a site to Favorites in Internet Explorer it is saved in the Favorites folder as an Internet Shortcut (.URL) file which is a text file.

[image: 1]

If you add a folder to Favorites in Windows Explorer it is saved in the Favorites folder as a Shortcut (.LNK) file.

[image: 2]

So basically you need to check your Favorites folder and see what's in there.